# UITableView: willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath: method - what does this method do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've stumbled upon one blog post where an author explains how to expand the size of a cell gradually while you scroll over the entire table view, using the following method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
}
```

However, when I implemented the above method in my view controller's implementation section, and ran the simulator, the result didn't look changed pre- and post-implementation.

So I then add `cell.textLabel.text = [UIColor greenColor];` just beneath `cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);` of the method above, and ran the simulator again, the screen didn't display any cells whose text is colored with green.

So what does this method do and when should I use it?

I create my template using master-detail application with core data, but even if I didn't  use core data it didn't change at all.

I'm on Xcode 5.0.2 and use iOS 7 simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `willDisplayCell:` instead of `willDisplayingCell:`?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Oops. I just changed it to the correct function name and everything is now working well. Actually, I first happened to select `didEndDisplayingCell:` and modified `didEnd` to `will`, without noticing the `ing` part. Sorry, my bad...

Comment: Yeah, I kind of hate optional methods... so easy to screw up without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

This method is `UITableViewDelegate`'s method, [[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillDisplayCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a)].

You should implement this delegate.

Comment: If you use master-detail application, it already conforms to the delegate, right? After all, methods like `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView: numberOfRowInSection` work well even if I don't set its delegate.